# Is there a way to disable "Advanced Settings" option in Dynamics 365?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales

Want to disable/hide the "Advanced Settings" option under Settings in Dynamics 365 as role based like no one should be able to access it or see it except system administrators. Is there anyway to do it ? If there is, would like to know the detailed steps.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to hide an entry in that menu or disable the direct url to access that settings.

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to disable the advanced Settings. Based on security role you can manage user group to see no of fraction feature into Advance Settings menu.